# Which class does getClass() report inside a constructor of a base class

Tags: java, constructor

In Java, is it safe to assume that `getClass()` called inside a constructor of a class used as a base class will provide information about the derived class, rather than the class of the base class?

It seems to work, but I guess that doesn't necessarily mean it's safe.
For example, if I have the following two classes:

```
public class Parent {
    public Parent() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class Derived extends Parent {
    public Derived() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Derived();
    }
}
```

When I run the `main()` method in the Derived class it prints: `Derived` (which is what I was hoping). But can I rely on that behavior across JVMs?

Comment: I would use it for logging purpose..

Comment: from java doc APIs, **Returns the runtime class of an object. That Class object is the object that is locked by static synchronized methods of the represented class.**

Comment: As to whether it's "safe" or not, I would say that depends a lot on what you plan to do with it. Are you really just logging the name? That doesn't seem terribly useful in the long run, but yes, that will be "safe," and will print out the actual class name being instantiated at runtime.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`getClass` is one of `Object`'s methods [and returns the **runtime** class of `this`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29):

> Returns the runtime class of this Object. The returned Class object is the object that is locked by static synchronized methods of the represented class.

So yes, it will always return `Derived`.