# Efficiently getting an object's attributes or enforcing declaration of class attribute

Tags: java, android, static, key-value-coding, kvc

**BACKGROUND SETTING**

I am trying to create a library for accessing and caching web service data in Android and have stumbled across a problem.

All the objects managed by my library inherit from a base `Entity` class. Any derivate class of `Entity` can declare other *fields** or *attributes**.

The base class is responsible for returning the `Entity` attributes that are to be read from cache (SQLite or File) or from a web service (REST or SOAP). In my current implementation, the `Entity` class performs this using reflection: it reads all class field names that are marked with an `@Attribute` annotation.

**PROBLEM**

The issue that I'm having in my implementation is the following: every time that I request all the `Entity`'s attributes using a function like `static Set<String> getAttributes()`, this function must create a `Set` implementation (currently using `HashSet` for that for fast look-up).

I would like to avoid allocating and initialising a `Set<String>` every time a request for all attributes is made.

From my point of view an attribute set is specific for an entire `Entity` class, not an `Entity` object. I.e.: having `class Customer extends Entity`, all `Customer` instances have the same exact attributes - each has a name, an address and so on.

My current attempt at this is to declare a `static Set<String> attributes` in every class that extends `Entity` and initialise that `Set` using reflection in the class' `static` block like this:

```
class Customer extends Entity 
{
   private static final Set<String> attributes = new HashSet<String>();

   static
   {
       Entity.populateAttributes(Customer.class);
   }
}
```

Given the class to initialise, the `Entity` class can look up all fields marked with the `@Attribute` annotation in that class and it's base classes (e.g. `Customer extends Person` and `Person extends Entity` would fill the `Customer.attributes` set with attributes declared for the `Customer` class and the ones inherited from the `Person` class).

The problem I have is that an `attributes` set might not be defined for a class which extends `Entity` and I would like to enforce that at compile time.

I have seen this being done for the `Serializable` interface in Eclipse: when create a class which implements `Serializable`, Eclipse shows a warning if your class does not declare a `[private] static final long serialVersionUID`.

**QUESTION**

Is there any way that I enforce that `Serializable` behaviour for my `Entity` class and show a warning or (better) an error if a class has not declared a field?

Is there a different approach to returning the attribute names for an `Entity`-derived class?

**FOOTNOTE**

**I used the term `field` for object properties that should not be managed by the library and the term `attribute` for object properties that should be managed by the library (be read from a web service or SQLite/File cache and be persisted in a web service or SQLite/File cache)*

**EDIT 1**

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is a to get a set of an `Entity`'s attributes* (see footnote above) in an efficient manner. This list is used by helper classes to store object values in a database (the `CREATE TABLE` queries can be deduced from the attribute names and types) or to send to a web-service.

This library is used for caching values from a web-service and for synchronizing the local database (which might contain extra user input values and might be missing server updated values for objects) with data accessible through a web-service. It is not intended to replace the use of per-field accessors/mutators in an application with generic accessors/mutators.

This concept is known as Key-Value Coding and is used by many frameworks and libraries. As an example, the first two examples of libraries using KVC that I've found with a Google search are Cocoa and Sproutcore. References: [Apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001838-SW1) and [Sproutcore wiki](http://wiki.sproutcore.com/w/page/12412967/Runtime-Key%20Value%20Coding).

KVC is also used in Android development. `Bundle`, `SQLiteCursor` and `ContentValues` make intense use of KVC.

Comment: "All the objects managed by my library inherit from a base Entity class. Any derivate class of Entity can declare other fields* or attributes*. " perhaps that is the heart of your problem. Why not use data members, getters and setters, like everyone else? Why try to build your own second-rate programming language on top of Java?

Comment: I am doing this so that the classes that handle the serialization/deserialization of objects to/from data sources can do this without having to be modified for every `Entity` added to the application. Also, the other way around (in case I move serialization/deserialization responsibility to the `Entity` classes): I want to be able to switch the serialization/deserialization class from, say, a JSON REST-ful service to a SOAP or an XML REST-ful service, without having to modify each `Entity` in the application.

Comment: "I am doing this so that the classes that handle the serialization/deserialization of objects to/from data sources can do this without having to be modified for every Entity added to the application" I'd say that was the tail wagging the dog. Java is an object-oriented programming language: design objects that have attributes, aggregates, associations and mutators. Move serialization into helper classes.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do above, but the helper classes need to know which fields to serialize for each `Entity` class. That is the purpose of the `getAttributes` method.

Comment: @Raedwald I've edited my question to include the reason that I'm trying to develop generic accessors/mutators. Sorry for not being more specific about my target use at first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I may not be able to enforce the declaration of a static field in the deriving classes' definition, I will go by storing a map of attribute sets and class descriptions in the definition of the `Entity` class described above and making sure that the set of attributes for a derived class is initialized in the `Entity` constructor.

As an example:

```
public class Entity
{
   private final static Map<Class<? extends Entity>, Set<String>> attributes = new HashMap<Class<? extends Entity>, Set<String>>();

   public static void populateAttributes(Class<? extends Entity> derivedClass)
   {
      //initialize the set of attributes for the derived class and 
      //add it to attributes map with "derivedClass" as key
   }

   static
   {
      populateAttributes(Entity.class);
   }

   public Entity()
   {
      //calling this.getClass() returns the object's actual (derived) class(*)
      if(!attributes.containsKey(this.getClass())
         populateAttributes(this.getClass());
   }

   //rest of class definition (including getAttributes method)
}

public class Customer extends Entity 
{
   @Attribute
   String someAttribute; //will be processed automatically
}
```

The cost of getting an `Entity`s attributes is reduced from parsing all class attributes and creating a new set to hold them to a check-and-retrieve operation on a `Map` which should be quite small when using a `HashMap`.

The cost of creating an `Entity` instance is increased by a check done to the attributes `Map` (fast on `HashMap`s). The cost of initializing the `attributes` set for a given class is negligible, as it is done only once per derivate class type.

Considering that the attributes are requested at least once per class instance on 90% or more of the occasions, this should give better overall performance than the initial solution described in the question.

(*)calling `this.getClass()` in a base class instance method will return the object's actual class. If the object has been initialized as a derived class instance, the derived class' description (`Class` object) will be returned. A question about this has already been asked and answered here: [Which class does getClass() report inside a constructor of a base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638504/safe-to-use-getclass-inside-a-constructor).